# A problem on group homomorphism .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Show that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two finite groups and the number of distinct group homomorphisms from $G_1$ to $H$ is equal to that of $G_2$ to $H$ for every finite group $H$, then that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic .

It's a problem in IMS 2014 .

Actually, I have tried to show $|G_1|= |G_2|$ , primarily, and if there exists an onto homomorphism from 
 $G_1$ onto $G_2$, then our assertion will be done.
But, I can't approach properly! 
[Here, I have found an answer on Aops](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h608719p3617698)

But, I want a different approach .

Comment: What machinery do you have at hand? If you've read Artin's book or Dummit's, how many chapters have you read?

Comment: @Mikhail D, Sir, I have read upto group homomorphisms, group actions, and some portions of finite abelian groups .

Comment: After some contemplatiin, I arrived too at what boils down to the proof you reference - now I can't unthink it :( -- Why do you desire a different approach? Is there something you on't like with this one?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen,Sir, actually, I thought the proof may use isomorphism theorems, or some theorems from Sylow's, but it mainly uses number theory, so I thought if it can be done on another way.